# Converting a hash-inside-array to single key multiple value hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to load data from redis db. I have a api only rails app and trying to render the json data as per requirement. 
Currently I am able to `get` the data from redis in the following format.

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Stephenie Meyer",
  "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "V.C. Andrews",
  "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z"
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Sophie Kinsella",
  "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z"
 }
]
```

How can convert this in a way such that the key value pairs  of `name`,`created` and `updated` will be hash to a `id` key-value pair.

Into this

```
 {"id": 1,
    {
      "name": "Stephenie Meyer",
      "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z",
      "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"
    }
 }
```

helper method for getting redis data.

```
def fetch_authors
    authors = $redis.get('authors')
    if authors.nil?
      authors = Author.all.to_json
      $redis.set("authors", authors).to_json
      $redis.expire("authors", 5.hour.to_i)
    end
    JSON.load authors
end
```

And displaying on index page using

```
def index
    @authors = fetch_authors
    render json: @authors
  end
```

Comment: “Something like” is not a valid ruby, hence the conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you want would probably be:

```
input = ...
input.map { |hash| [hash.delete(:id) || hash.delete('id'), hash] }.to_h

#⇒ {{1=>{:name=>...},
#   {2=>{:name=>...},
#   {3=>{:name=>...}}
```

Comment: `[
null,
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Stephenie Meyer",
"created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z",
"updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"
}
],`  This is what it is producing. Is there anyway I can get id in the place of `null`?

Comment: @user3576036 That wouldn't be the result, Instead, this would be the result `{1=>{:name=>"Stephenie Meyer", :created_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z", :updated_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"}, 2=>{:name=>"V.C. Andrews", :created_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z", :updated_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z"}, 3=>{:name=>"Sophie Kinsella", :created_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z", :updated_at=>"2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z"}}
`

Comment: Ok. I am not getting the id number too then. Its giving null. `@authors` is the array input I am supposed to give.

Comment: @Stefan you gotta be kidding. Since `"foo":` syntax was allowed for hashes, `{"foo": 42} #⇒ {:foo=>42}`. Note the original hash is not `{"foo" => 42}`.

Comment: @mudasobwa no kidding, just not enough coffee. I really saw a `=>` in there ;-)

Comment: @Stefan that would be a great conference lightning talk title: “Lack of coffee as a main cause of hashrockets.” :)

Comment: Oh wait ... that's JSON! The resulting Ruby hash probably does have string keys.

Comment: @Stefan how would you know without fortunetelling it’s JSON? It’s perfectly valid ruby 2.3+.

Comment: @Stefan better now? :-P

Comment: Because of `JSON.load authors`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want because that's not correct syntax but you can achieve something similar with [**`group_by`**](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by)

```
arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stephenie Meyer",
    "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "V.C. Andrews",
    "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Sophie Kinsella",
    "created_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z"
  }
]

arr.group_by { |e| e[:id] }
```

This will return

```
{
    1 => [
        {
                    :id => 1,
                  :name => "Stephenie Meyer",
            :created_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z",
            :updated_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.417Z"
        }
    ],
    2 => [
        {
                    :id => 2,
                  :name => "V.C. Andrews",
            :created_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z",
            :updated_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.613Z"
        }
    ],
    3 => [
        {
                    :id => 3,
                  :name => "Sophie Kinsella",
            :created_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z",
            :updated_at => "2018-04-17T07:40:50.646Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its returning the same array. I called  `group_by` on `@authors` array. but no changes.

Comment: @user3576036 `group_by` doesn't modify its receiver (an array can't be turned into a hash). It returns a new array instead.